# Unisharp Laravel File Manager where /public is \public_html

Tags: laravel, unisharp-file-manager

I am using Laravel 8. My site's public directory is public_html and I have made the appropriate changed to the appservice provider:

```
 public function register()
{
     $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path().'/public_html';
     });
}
```

and changed the lfm is config to

```
'base_directory' => 'public_html',
```

The filemanager is uploading to the correct directory and making thumbnails in a subdirectory correctly, but it's view is a broken symbol.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: have you re-run `php artisan storage:link` after you made your changes?  And changed the SymLink paths in filesystems config file? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: I have changed the filesystem to
`'public' => [
          'driver' => 'local',
              'root' => storage_path('app/public_html'),
             'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public_html',
             'visibility' => 'public',
        ], `
but still the URL is given as `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://quislingmovie.com/vendor/laravel-filemanager/img/folder.png">`

The storage link has been run.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to display the image?

Comment: It is called by CKEditor

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the new storage path to the app instance. Please try this:

**AppServiceProvider**

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->app->instance('path.storage', base_path() . '/public_html');
}
```

Comment: I have already got such a binding:

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
                return base_path().'/public_html';
         });

Comment: @Jim they different. Take a look please. You can replace them and try it out.

Comment: It has made no difference. It is giving the route as https://quislingmovie.com/laravel-filemanager/photos/shares/6183cadfd8b51.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the `/laravel-filemanager/` prefix from the src **URLs**.
you have got the `photos` as a route.
example:

https://quislingmovie.com/photos/shares/6183cadfd8b51.jpg

[image: https://quislingmovie.com/photos/shares/6183cadfd8b51.jpg]

[image]

Comment: @Jim I didn't understand that "amendment stopped the whole site working!" .
are you talking about the "substituting the url" or another amendment?

Comment: I have reached out your website, and i didnt noticed any problem. actually one of the pictures on the answer is serving from your website

Comment: The problem is filemanager is not showing the items properly. The images are OK because I had remove the extra part of the URL.

Comment: @Jim so the problem with the question (not showing the picture) has been resolved with correct url.

Comment: "The problem is filemanager is not showing the items properly." is another problem i guess.

Comment: Yes. It is just not working properly